# CentOS 6 gnome-terminal font is garbled until Arabic Support is installed

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, gnome

My default VM images for CentOS 6 are always installed with the most minimal set of packages.  When I need a machine with a graphical install, I upgrade with `yum groupinstall Desktop`.  I've noticed that this installation produces bad fonts in gnome-terminal, until I install the Arabic Language support, per the CentOS open [bug](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=5178):

```
yum groupinstall "Arabic Support"
```

... this rather comically fixes it mid-package install in the open terminal, and I can add Arabic Support if I really need to (or figure out which package is needed).

Any ideas on how to do this without installing Arabic Support?

I thought this might have been a VMware thing, but it happens on bare-metal kickstarts I'm doing as well.  I'm also making the assumption that this is a byproduct of not installing a graphical desktop package group from the initial install (and I'm guessing this is why the CentOS bug is still open).

Answer (score 2):

The package you need to install is `dejavu-sans-mono-fonts`. This is the default monospace font used by GNOME and KDE. You may also wish to install the variable width DejaVu fonts as well. Those are in the `dejavu-sans-fonts` package.

Comment: Great answer - thanks.  I always run headless w/CentOS, so I had never noticed this before!